# delete duplicate records without having any primary id

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `ComplimentTransactAssign_tbl`. In this table there are a lot of duplicate entries. Table structure is like this:

```
TransactID           Cmplid     
-
32                      16          
105                     17          
105                     17        
290                     12         
32                      16
290                     12
```

I find out my duplicate records like this:

```
select TransactID  from ComplimentTransactAssign_tbl
  group by TransactID having count(*) >1 order by TransactID
```

I want to delete duplicate records. After deleting I want to get output like this:

```
TransactID           Cmplid     
-
32                      16          
105                     17                 
290                     12
```

Comment: if three with same TransactID i want to delete 2 records..only i want to keep one record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT TransactID ,
           Cmplid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransactID ORDER BY TransactID) AS row_num
    FROM ComplimentTransactAssign_tbl cta
)   
DELETE FROM MyCTE 
WHERE row_num <> 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f85f/3)

Comment: Error is showing last line(WHERE row_num<>1).Invalid column name 'row_num'

Comment: have you seen the example in the fiddle? This works. Have you named the last column of the CTE as row_num?